# KDE Plasma Show Desktop Icon

Tags: linux, linux-mint, desktop, kde, kde-plasma-5

I'm new to linux, I used to use windows 10, and I'm using linux mint with kde plasma desktop.

I want to display Computer and trash icons on desktop like windows, How to do that?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: I'm new to linux,   .... Use Linux as it comes to learn it. I use an Xfce desktop in Kali and it it nicely like Windows 10. I looked at doing this in Ubuntu but I would have to uninstall Wayland. That possibly had other implications. Best overall to adapt to the OS you are using.

Comment: @John Do you mean I can't show desktop icons?

Comment: I set Ubuntu and Kali so that Desktop icons are the "task bar" (both systems) so everything is available to me all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose when installing KDE plasma you also installed dolphin as your file manager.

1. Open dolphin, e.g. by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
2. On the left side you see various folders, with the title "Places".
3. Simply drag and drop the folder you want to have on your desktop
4. If a menu pops up, click "Link here"

You can create shortcuts (links to be precise) of whatever file/folder you like and in whatever directory you like, not only on your desktop.

Comment: Thanks, it works.

Comment: Nice answer.  Better than mine.  +1.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Please do not delete your answer. It very likely still can be a very valuable piece of information for someone!

Answer (score 3):

These things don't work the same as they do in Windows but here is something close.

**For the trash can**

1. Right click on the Desktop and choose "Add Widgets..."
2. Type "Trash" in the search box.
3. Drag the trashcan widget over to your desktop.

**For the "Computer"**

1. Click your KDE menu icon.
2. Drag "File Manager" over to the desktop and link it.
3. Rename.

These will not function exactly like the windows desktop but this is about as close as you are going to get.

Comment: I am not happy with the solution for the trash can, because widgets won't behave like usual links and files on the desktop in terms of moving them. You would need to enter edit mode first.